# Poker game, bad signals for pairs, threes and pokers

Tags: c

I was trying to do a problem from Dietels ,,C how to program - 7th edition" book. It says that I should deal two five card hands and see which is better. I didn't even make it to the hand comparison, and I have a huge problem.
In this code that I will give you, signals for a pair,three,poker,flush and straight aren't good. They should turn to 2, if there are 2 pairs of cards, and that's only for signal "pair", and 1, if the program finds a pair, a three-of-a-kind, a four-of-a-kind, straight or flush. Instead, it always gives me a bigger number than 1, even if I set my variables to be equal to 0,1 or 2. (see the first switch function in my code.)
The output is good, it tells me what I have in my hand correctly, but increments and equation statements are not, it gives me garbage.
Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? Is it something with if{do while} part of my function or..?

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SUITS 4
#define FACES 13
#define CARDS 52

void deal( unsigned int wDeck[][ FACES ], const char *wFace[],const char *wSuit[], char hand[6][150] ){
size_t row;
size_t column;
size_t card;

for ( card = 0; card <= 5; ++card ) {
    for ( row = 0; row < SUITS; ++row ) {
        for ( column = 0; column < FACES; ++column ) {
            if ( wDeck[ row ][ column ] == card ) {
                strcat(hand[card],wFace[column]);
                strcat(hand[card]," ");
                strcat(hand[card],wSuit[row]);
            }
        }
    }
}
}

void shuffle( unsigned int wDeck[][ FACES ] ) {
  size_t row;
  size_t column;
  size_t card;

   for ( card = 1; card <= CARDS; ++card ) {
     do {
         row = rand() % SUITS;
         column = rand() % FACES;
     } while( wDeck[ row ][ column ] != 0 );

     wDeck[ row ][ column ] = card;
 }
}

int fixNshow (char hand[6][150], char handFIXED[5][150]){
char faces[5][20];
char suits[5][20];
char *token;

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    strcpy(handFIXED[i],hand[i+1]);
}
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    printf("%s\n",handFIXED[i]);
}

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
   token=strtok(handFIXED[i]," ");
     if(token!=NULL){
       strcpy(faces[i],token);
       token=strtok(NULL," ");
       if(token!=NULL){
         strcpy(suits[i],token);
       }
     }
}
printf("\n");

//Evaluating the hand.

int pair=0;
int three=0;
int poker=0;
int flush=0;
int straight=0;
int no=0;
int tokentwo=0;
int pass=2;
int j=1;
int g=1;
char faceatm[5][20],suitatm[20];
int hardness[4];
int swap=0;
int temp=0;
int totalpoints=0;
int highcard=0;
//Pairs, tripples, pokers, two pairs
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    j=i+1;
    g=i;
    no=0;
    strcpy(faceatm[i],faces[i]);

    if(i>0){                                    //THIS
        do{                                     //WHOLE
            pass=strcmp(faceatm[i],faceatm[g-1]);//PART RESOLVES
            g--;                                  //DUPLICATE
            if (pass==0){                         //APPEARANCE
                break;                            //OF
            }                                     //MATCHES
        }while(g>0);                              //EXAMPLE
    }                                             //JACK
    if (pass==0){                                 //JACK JACK
        continue;                                 //TEN, QUEEN
    }                                             //SIGNALS THAT ARE EQUAL TO 1 ARE: TRIPPLE,PAIR. THIS PREVENTS IT.

    if(j<5){
      do{
         tokentwo=strcmp(faceatm[i],faces[j]);
          if(tokentwo==0){
              no++;
              printf("ITERATION NUMBER %d, NO=%d\n",i,no);
           }
           j++;
       }while(j<5);
    }
    switch(no){
        case 1: printf("Pair of %ss\n",faceatm[i]); pair++;  break;
        case 2: printf("Three of %ss\n",faceatm[i]); three++;  break;
        case 3: printf("Poker of %ss\n",faceatm[i]); poker++; break;
    }
}
//Flush catcher
strcpy(suitatm,suits[0]);
do{
  tokentwo=strcmp(suitatm,suits[j]);
  if(tokentwo==0){
    no++;
  }
  j++;
}while(j<5);
if(no==4){
    printf("FLUSH OF %s",suitatm);
    flush++;
}
//Straight catcher
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    if(strcmp("Ace",faces[i])==0){
        hardness[i]=1;
    }
    else if(strcmp("Deuce",faces[i])==0){
       hardness[i]=2;
    }
    else if(strcmp("Three",faces[i])==0){
        hardness[i]=3;
    }
    else if(strcmp("Four",faces[i])==0){
       hardness[i]=4;
    }
    else if(strcmp("Five",faces[i])==0){
       hardness[i]=5;
    }
    else if(strcmp("Six",faces[i])==0){
       hardness[i]=6;
    }
    else if(strcmp("Seven",faces[i])==0){
       hardness[i]=7;
    }
    else if(strcmp("Eight",faces[i])==0){
       hardness[i]=8;
    }
    else if(strcmp("Nine",faces[i])==0){
       hardness[i]=9;
    }
    else if(strcmp("Ten",faces[i])==0){
       hardness[i]=10;
    }
    else if(strcmp("Jack",faces[i])==0){
       hardness[i]=11;
    }
    else if(strcmp("Queen",faces[i])==0){
       hardness[i]=12;
    }
    else if(strcmp("King",faces[i])==0){
       hardness[i]=13;
    }
}

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
        if(hardness[i]>hardness[i+1]){
            swap=hardness[i];
            hardness[i]=hardness[i+1];
            hardness[i+1]=swap;
        }
    }
}
if(hardness[0]==hardness[1]-1==hardness[2]-2==hardness[3]-3==hardness[4]-4){
    straight++;
}
//End of hand evaluation
//Points
highcard=hardness[4];
    if(pair==0 && three==0 && poker==0 && straight==0 && flush==0){totalpoints=highcard;}
    else if(pair==1 && three==0 && poker==0 && straight==0 && flush==0){totalpoints=14;}
    else if(pair==2 && three==0 && poker==0 && straight==0 && flush==0){totalpoints=15;}
    else if(pair==0 && three==1 && poker==0 && straight==0 && flush==0){totalpoints=16;}
    else if(pair==0 && three==0 && poker==0 && straight==1 && flush==0){totalpoints=17;}
    else if(pair==0 && three==0 && poker==0 && straight==0 && flush==1){totalpoints=18;}
    else if(pair==1 && three==1 && poker==0 && straight==0 && flush==0){totalpoints=19;}
    else if(pair==0 && three==0 && poker==1 && straight==0 && flush==0){totalpoints=20;}
    else if(pair==0 && three==0 && poker==0 && straight==1 && flush==1){ 
        if(hardness[0]==1 && hardness[1]==10 && hardness[2]==11 && hardness[3]==12 && hardness[4]==13){
            totalpoints=22;
        }
        else {
            totalpoints=21;
        }    
    }
return totalpoints;
}
#endif
```

This is my main:

```
#include "functions.h"

int main(void) {

const char *suit[ SUITS ] ={ "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades" };
const char *face[ FACES ] ={ "Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four",
                             "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight",
                             "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };
unsigned int deck[ SUITS ][ FACES ] = { 0 };
char hand[6][150]={""};
char handFIXED[5][150]={""};
int handpoints;

srand( time( NULL ) );

shuffle( deck );
deal(deck,face,suit,hand);
handpoints=fixNshow(hand,handFIXED);
printf("HAND STRONGNESS: %d",handpoints);

}
```

So, my output is this when I run my game:

```
Ace Diamonds
Five Clubs
Five Spades
Jack Spades
Five Hearts

ITERATION NUMBER 1, NO=1
ITERATION NUMBER 1, NO=2
Three of Fives
HAND STRONGNESS: 19
RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 347ms)
```

It gives me a good information about what I have in my hand, but this hand strongness is by no means good. It means that my pair signal is 1, which it shouldn't be.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At first glance, and probably unrelated to your problem: It looks as if you implemented the poker stuff in the header, `functions.h`. In this simple program it doesn't matter, but the header should only export the interface, that is function prototypes, type and struct definitions and requires enums, to an implementation in `function.c`.

Comment: Also, `if (a == b == c == d)` does not do what you think. You have to chain such comparisons with the logical operators `&&` and `||`: `if  (a == b && a == c && a == d)...` (Such mistakes are easy to find when you turn on warnings.)

Comment: _signals for a pair,three,poker,flush and straight aren't good_ is not a particularly descriptive diagnosis and it does nothing to tell us what you've already tried in order to debug this for yourself. (Additionally, there's no such poker hand rank as a "poker"... perhaps you mean four-of-a-kind here?)

Comment: The strange strongness probably comes from an uninitialised value of `totalpoints` in `fixNshow`. None of your cases match, so it isn't overwritten with a sensible value and you get garbage.

Comment: It is also not a good idea to represent the card suits and ranks as strings. A better way is to represent a card as struct of two enums (one for rank, one for suit) and then create a printing function that prints a card. The enumeration of ranks will directly map to a value (with the exception that an ace may be lowest or hightest, but that must be decided in context anyway.)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. We call four-of-a-kind "poker" here in Serbia, so that is why I named this signal like so.

Comment: We call four-of-a-kind "poker" here in Serbia, so that is why I named this signal like so. Will fix my question, thank you for notice.
@MOehm Well, In this book, they didn't mention structs yet, so I guess I should do it like this. I guess I should do the whole book before I get to this problem.

Comment: It's not forbidden to use strings to represent the cards, but C isn't really suited to that approach. It is, in general, better to choose a "natural" representation and then write some code to print it. That gives you, for example, `==` instead of `strcmp` and `=` instead of `strcpy`. If you don't know about structs yet, you can also represent the cards with a number from 0 to51. Then, the rank (0-12) is `n % 13` and the suit (0-3)  is `n / 13`.

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability by us humans: 1) consistently indent the code (suggest 4 spaces per indent level as that is visible even with variable width fonts) Indent after every opening brace '{'. Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) by a blank line. 3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: strongly suggest having small functions that do one thing very well rather these large functions, like `main()` that try to do the world

Comment: the function: `shuffle()` is being called from `main()` however the function does not exist within the posted code.

Comment: this line does not compile correctly,  Please correct and post as an edit.

Comment: the variable `temp` is initialized, but never assigned and never used, suggest removing that variable

Comment: the variable `flush` is used in the `fixNshow()` function but is never initialized.

Comment: this kind of line: `int flush,straight=0;` only initializes `straight` to 0.  the assignment has no effect on the `flush` variable, so it contains what ever trash is on the stack at the point in memory. (and stack, unlike the heap, does not get initialized to 0).  I see this error several places in the code

Comment: the variable `cont` is initialized to 0 but never used.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings and fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` (I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` ) )

Comment: the posted code contains many 'magic' numbers. 'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  I.E. 4,5,6,14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20. 21, 22,150 could be part of an enum the values used in the switch() cases would be more understandable as entries in an enum.  The values used to set `hardness` would be much more understandable as member of an enum.  The idea of using an enum or several #define statements is to give those numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: one more important item.  DO NOT place source code in a header file.  Rather give the source code its' own `features.c` file and only have #defines, struct definitions, enum definitions, and function prototypes in the `features.h` files.  Do not place any variable declarations (extern statements are good for variables) nor C code in a header file.

Comment: @user3629249 I will fix everything you said, and I will update you guys.
Function shuffle() exists in my code, but it looks like I didn't write it here, thats fixed.
It could be that I didn't initialize my variables one at a time.
I am using netbeans IDE, and it isn't giving me any warnings.

Comment: Oh my god, bad initialization of variables was indeed the problem. I don't know what I was thinking when I tried to initialize them. Thank you @user3629249

Comment: And thank you everyone for telling me how to make a good code, I will use you suggestions from now on.